# How to imlement ReactiveUserDetailsService with MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-security

There in Spring security 5 appear an interface as [ReactiveUserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/ReactiveUserDetailsService.html).

Now my question is how to implement UserDetailsService using:

- Spring-data-Mongo

  Spring Security (5)

**That I have (users stored in memory)**

```
@Bean
public MapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("test").password("password").roles("USER").build();
    UserDetails admin = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("admin").password("admin").roles("USER", "ADMIN").build();
    return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user, admin);
}
```

**What I want:**

```
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private LocalDate createdAt;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean accountNonLocker;
    private boolean enabled;
    @DBRef
    private List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities;
    //getters and setters
}


@Component
public class SecUserDetailsService implements ReactiveUserDetailsService {

}
```

And I don't know how to implement it. not found any resources on web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already found a solution:

Implement `UserDetails` interface in `UseAccount` class and create Role class that implements `GrantedAuthority` interface:

**Role**

```
@Data
@Document
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

**UseAcount**

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document
public class UserAccount implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String idnp;

    @Email
    private String email;

    @Builder.Default()
    private boolean active = true;

    @Builder.Default()
    @DBRef
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return active;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return active;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return active;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return active;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Define **Security configuration** and in it create web filter.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/login", "/logout").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/i18n/**",
                    "/css/**",
                    "/fonts/**",
                    "/icons-reference/**",
                    "/img/**",
                    "/js/**",
                    "/vendor/**").permitAll()
            .anyExchange()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .and()
            .build();
    }


    //in case you want to encrypt password
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Create repository to extract your user from database.

And last step is to create **UserDetailsService**

```
@Component
public class SecUserDetailsService implements ReactiveUserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    public ReactiveUserAccountRepository reactiveUserAccountRepository;


    @Override
    public Mono<UserDetails> findByUsername(String username) {
        Mono<UserAccount> data = reactiveUserAccountRepository.findByUsername(username);
        return data.cast(UserDetails.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you do when `reactive UserAccount Repository.findByUsername(username);` does not consist username and send in response NULL ?

Comment: @makson is just throws an error and redirect u to login page with query param `error`